# SQL Decrease field by the amount of previous record field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sum

I have a query that delivers some inventory results.  The query looks at the Item number and with a Join to a a Inventory table  and retrieves the amount in stock (InStock)

```
SUM(di.[Count])as Requested,
ISNULL(mt.qty,0) as InStock,
```

What I get then is a results like this:

[image]

Which is correct however, what I like to be able to do is  decease  the **InStock** the amount by the amount from the previous record.

[image]

What I have tried and for obvious reason this didn't work:

```
(ISNULL(mt.qty, 0) - SUM(di.[Count])) as Inventory,
```

I'm looking into something like this but never used Partition or Over before :

```
sum(mt.qty) over (order by di.InventoryNumber asc) as Inventory
```

below is my full query:

```
SELECT ISNUll(mt.cart,'Not Assigned') as Cart,

                   c.ClientName AS Client,

                   di.InventoryNumber AS IMS_Number,

                   SUM(di.[Count])as Requested, 

                   ISNULL(mt.qty,0) as InStock,

                   (ISNULL(mt.qty, 0) - SUM(di.[Count])) as Inventory, 

                    CASE di.IsManual  
                       WHEN 0 THEN 'Auto'
                       WHEN 1 THEN 'Manual'
                     END As Operation,

                     CASE WHEN mt.item IS NULL THEN 'New' ELSE 'In Stock' END as Availability,

                     CASE jl.LocationId 
                        WHEN 0 THEN 'Both'
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Bond'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Woodlands'
                     END AS Location,

                     CAST (di.ItemDescription AS TEXT) as Descriptions,
                     di.ItemType AS [Type]


                         FROM linwdc1f.eFulfillment2.dbo.DailyInventoryView di 

                          INNER JOIN linwdc1f.eFulfillment2.dbo.JobConfigs jc ON di.JobName=jc.JobName 
                          INNER JOIN linwdc1f.eFulfillment2.dbo.Clients c ON di.ClientId=c.ClientId 
                          INNER JOIN linwdc1f.eFulfillment2.dbo.JobLocations jl ON  jl.JobName = di.JobName AND jl.LocationId=2
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN linwdc1f.eFulfillment2.dbo.printjobs pj on pj.JobName =di.JobName
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN linwdc1f.eFulfillment2.dbo.PrintComponents pc on pc.id = pj.PrintComponentId
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN linwdc1f.eFulfillment2.dbo.ProjectJobs prj on prj.id = pc.ProjectJobId
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN Master mt on di.InventoryNumber = mt.item 

                        WHERE di.JobDate BETWEEN '2016-08-08' AND '2016-08-08'  AND prj.ProjectJobName IS NULL

                        GROUP BY c.ClientName, mt.cart, di.InventoryNumber,c.ClientName ,mt.qty,mt.item,jl.LocationId,di.ItemDescription,di.ItemType,di.IsManual
                        Order by di.InventoryNumber,c.ClientName, mt.cart
```

Comment: Have you explored Lag/Lead?

Comment: What version of sql-server do you have?

Comment: To take advantage of lag/lead you need something to order that data by. Do you have an order id field to order the sample data you provided?

Comment: Chris@ 2014 professional, Yes the IMS_Number field is unique.

Comment: According to what you stated, it's hard to give an answer. Your question would require some kinds of order on the data set, and the data set you gave does not give any condition to produce this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a column like "RequestID" to identity each record in your Request table. Make the modification accordingly please.

Make sure you use SQL Server 2012 and above, because I used LAG function which is a new func since SS 2012. Tested, it works perfect in SSMS. :)

```
--Create table structure
create table #stock (IMS_Number varchar(10), InStocked int)
go

create table #request (requestID int identity(1,1), IMS_Number varchar(10), Requested int, RequestDate date)
go


--Insert into sample Data
insert #stock values ('H000092229', 3),('H111108880',8)

insert #request 
select 'H000092229', 2, '08-09-2016'
union all
select 'H000092229', 3, '08-09-2016'
union all
select 'H000092229', 3, '08-09-2016'
union all
select 'H000092229', 3, '08-09-2016'
union all
select 'H000092229', 1, '08-09-2016'

select * from #stock
select * from #request


--Below is the solution
select 
    IMS_number, 
    Requested, 
    case    when RID = 1 
            then instocked 
            else LAG(instockReal,1,0)over(order by requestid) 
    end as InStocked
from
(
    select  b.requestid, 
            a.instocked, 
            b.IMS_number, 
            b.requested, 
            sum(b.requested)over(partition by b.IMS_number order by b.requestid) * (-1) + a.instocked as instockReal,
            row_number()over(partition by b.ims_number order by requestid) as RID
    from #request b
    join #stock a
    on b.IMS_Number = a.IMS_Number
) as ab
```

By the way, in the target result set, the last record should be -8 instead of -6.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dance-Henry@ Thank you it works well except when the stock is zero. I thought that if the stock was zero then the instocked would be the negative of the Requested value . This I think I can fix . thanks again